# Netty 4.x get body data without HttpObjectAggregator

Tags: java, netty

I have one problem that if HttpObjectAggregator used I can get body data from FullHttpRequest but can not upload large file (netty return 413 code). Remove HttpObjectAggregator from pipeline so upload large file is ok, but can not get body data. 
Anyone can help me to solve this problem?

Here some configures pipeline I have tried:

1.Get body data ok, can not upload big file

```
p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());

p.addLast("agg", new HttpObjectAggregator(1024*1024));

p.addLast(new HttpFileServerHandler());
```

2.Upload big file ok but can not get body data

```
p.addLast(new HttpServerCodec());

p.addLast(new HttpFileServerHandler());
```

Answer (score 0):

You most likely need to configure `HttpObjectAggregator` with a bigger max message size. Alternative you can also remove it from the pipeline and just "merge" the `HttpRequest` and `HttpContent` chunks until `LastHttpContent` is received.